# "Cannot read property of undefined" in React after fetching and waiting

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm new in React, and I have a problem with fetching:

I have been doing a project in react where I have to fetch from five different URLs depending on which company the user selects.
I've changed the code many times, but it won't work.

I tried with componentDidMount (but it is only called once, and I want to fetch many URLs), with `while(!this.state)` to busy wait the fetch to get the data before assign it, etc.

Fetch function:

```
async fetch_data() {
    var sel = this.props.select;
    symbol = companies[sel];
    url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=' + func + '&symbol=' + symbol + '&outputsize=' + osize + '&apikey=' + api_key;
    var response = await fetch(url);
    var data = await response.json();
    
    while(!data);

    this.setState({data: data, loading: false });
    this.setValues();    
  }
```

Set values function (trimmed so it's not so long):

```
setValues() {
    day = this.state.data["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"];
    open = this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["1. open"];
    higher = this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["2. high"];
  }
```

Render function (also trimmed):

```
render() {
    
    this.fetch_data();
    if(this.state.loading || !this.state || !this.state.data) {
      return <div>Loading :D...</div>
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Symbol: {symbol}</h2>
          <p>Url: {url}</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Open price: {open}
            </li>
            <li>
              Higher price: {higher}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I actually have done the part when the user selects a company, and the symbol (and the URL) changes...
But the problem is that when the program wants to access `this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["1. open"];`, for example, it crashes because it is fetching and receiving data.

The error says:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '3. Last Refreshed' of undefined:

  42 | setValues() {
> 43 |   day = this.state.data["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"];
     | ^  44 |   open = this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["1. open"];
  45 |   higher = this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["2. high"];
```

The app doesn't always crashes, and it shows the results, but the render component keeps calling this.fetch_data() and it crashes because sometimes (like 80% of the times) the data hasn't arrived and I'm trying to access it.

Comment: You can remove `while(!data);`. The `await` keyword will make sure `data` is assigned a value before `setState` is called.

Comment: try this replace this.setValues() to requestAnimationFrame(this.setValues)

Comment: It doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

Just put an if statement before return in render saying "Does the symbol has changed? If yes, fetch, else dont"

Comment: What did you mean by "Does the symbol has changed"? What method/solution did you use? I have the same issue in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this because you are calling this.fetch_data(); inside render()
that's mean first you have no data in your state and after there is a data you are updating your component, so you are calling again and again this.fetch_data();

take a look for React component lifecycle: https://code.likeagirl.io/understanding-react-component-life-cycle-49bf4b8674de

another thing no need to write while() because you are using async await.

Comment: What can I do then to call the function fetch only when the var "symbol" changes its value? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is that [`setState()` is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3). What this means in your case is that the state changes made here:

```
this.setState({data: data, loading: false });
```

Are not immediately observable on the subsequent call to `this.setValues();` (which itself is reliant on the `data` object being defined in the component's state). 
The solution for these situations is to use the second callback argument on the `setState()` method to run logic that is dependant on the corresponding state change:

```
/* The state change will be observable when setValues() is called via
the callback */
this.setState({data: data, loading: false }, () => {

    this.setValues();    
});
```

As a suggestion for your component's implementation, consider revising the `render()` method so that `day`, `open`, and `higher` are accessed and rendered in `render()` directly, rather than to cache those values elsewhere as you appear to be doing. So try something like this:

```
render() {

    this.fetch_data();
    if(this.state.loading || !this.state || !this.state.data) {
      return <div>Loading :D...</div>
    } else {

      /* Call to setValues() no longer needed */

      const day = this.state.data["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"];
      const open = this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["1. open"];
      const higher = this.state.data["Time Series (Daily)"][day]["2. high"];

      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Symbol: {symbol}</h2>
          <p>Url: {url}</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Open price: {open}
            </li>
            <li>
              Higher price: {higher}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have modified the function render as you've said, but it crashed the same way :(

Comment: can you include a copy of the json response your `fetch()` request returns?